# OneNote Alternative

Tags: gratis, text-editor, document-management

I work for a small MSP and we currently use OneNote to manage our client documentation.  The search and dynamic method of creating pages is nice but there is one drawback I'm hoping someone has a solution to:  Dynamic templates.

We use templates to create documentation but our process is copying a master template and filling it out for each client.  The problem comes when we want to add a new field - it's painful to add this new field to the rest of the clients.  It must be done manually for each client.  I would LOVE to be able to update the master template and have it propagate to all 'child' templates created from it.

Is there are alternative (and free!) application out there which will do this or is there an add-on or method in which to do this within OneNote?  Google searches come up empty for me.

Thank you.

Comment: DITA is designed for this. You Would define your templates and content as DITA XML, and use DITA software. I can recommend "Componize" but I don't know about free implementations unfortunately. Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darwin_Information_Typing_Architecture and tell us whether this standard could fit in your scenario.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Offline alternative to OneNote / Evernote](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/24747/offline-alternative-to-onenote-evernote)