# Free OneNote Alternative?

Tags: windows, gratis, note-taking, microsoft-onenote

I am currently using OneNote (Windows 10) for note taking.  But I am finding lots of issues with it.  For example, selecting large note by scrolling is extremely slow but there are many more issues.

Troubling part is that the issues I am seeing existed years ago, so I am looking for a free alternative.

I am looking for something that will allow me to:

- take notes fast,
- add/remove screenshots,
- search all notes for text,
- access them from various devices,
- organize them nicely (this is another annoying part in OneNote),
- etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Offline alternative to OneNote / Evernote](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/24747/offline-alternative-to-onenote-evernote)

Answer (score 1):

[GNotes](http://gnotes.me/)

I'm currently using it for all of my note taking needs. It supports 'simple' notes like normal notes, list, and images. I don't think they're planning on adding videos (although I'm not sure any note takers support videos ATM). On PCs you can access your notes from the web, there's also an [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.dayup.gnotes) and [IOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/gnotes-by-appest/id569843819?mt=8) port.

There are currently some bugs ATM and I'm hoping they fix it all soon as this is my favourite free alternative. There are many out there, but I think this is the simplest of the bunch.

Comment: It is slick but it has some issues with pasting image, i.e. I can not paste an image where I want in my note but only attach to the note at the bottom.  Don't like that.  I should be able to place images anywhere in my note just like in OneNote.  Otherwise, it is nice, simple, slick, I tried it.  Thanks

Comment: ah i see, so youd like to place an image somewhere and have text surrounding it instead of an attached image. IIRC only the big named note takers support this --- currently im waiting for fiinote PC - https://www.fiinote.com and android - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fiistudio.fiinote&hl=en, but they currently dont have a web ui yet

Comment: No, I don't care if text wraps around image or not.  As long as the image shows where I paste it into document.  OneNote does it perfectly but it has its annoyances which I described.  And really allowing an image to be added only at the very end of a note (or allowing only one image) makes zero sense.  Imagine yourself being a student and taking notes in a class.  The note might be 10 pages long with 5 image in it and the images could be anywhere in the note.  One of major annoyances with OneNote is how slow it is to scroll and select the text in the note but there are more annoyances with it

Comment: Can GNotes open existing .one files from OneNote?

Answer (score -1):

I believe EverNote can function as you desire:

```
https://evernote.com/pricing/
```

I have used EverNote; and you can access your EverNote items from any PC (web browser - Win/Linux/Mac), as well as up to two (2) devices for **free**. It works really well, and I've not had any issues with reliability.

Also, in addition to "just" notes, for **free** you can:

```
Upload up to 60 MB per month
Stay organized across platforms
Clip web pages and images
Search for text inside images!!!
Share and discuss notes
Add passcode lock on mobile apps
Integrates with Google Drive
```

... and based upon a previous note, it does in-line images as well:

[image: Evernote In-Line Image Sample]

Finally, in the vein of a "todo" list... to any "note" you can add a [checkbox] to function in the traditional manner.

Have fun!