# "Local" notes - combined with cloud

Tags: windows, offline, note-taking

I am looking for an 'offline' note platform that runs on Windows 10 and Windows 7. I will be using this for both personal and work related, so some schema for splitting the two would be preferential. To break down the content:

**Work**

I work as an IT technician, so the main brunt of my notes will be:

- Code (HTML, CSS, Visual Basic)
- Scripts (Batch, PowerShell, Phython and Visual Basic)
- General notes (from meetings, personal notes)
- Web URL and logins (obviously not plain-text)

**Personal**

My personal notes will entail a large variety:

- Personal to-do list
- Personal reminders (shopping, bills etc.)
- General reminders pertaining to family/friends

I do not want to run a service that ties to an account (so no subscription based software), things such as Google Notes/Evernote are therefore out.

Now, because I want to run this instance across 1-10 PCs I need to ensure the integrity of the files. I do not want someone to log into my work PC during my absence and whilst not under my UserID be able to launch the program and correlate the notes. It needs to be secure.

I would prefer encryption with a user password. I do not want to be able to simply relate the 'data' to the application.

To summarize my **needs** are:

- Must run on Windows 7 and 10
- Must be secure - in relation to accessing data
- Must allow importing data, without tying to third party subscriptions

It would be **nice to have**:

- Ability to format text in a nice UI
- Ability to add links as Hyperlinks
- Ability to attach PDF/Docs etc.
- Ability to add categories to data

I do not mind a one-time payments for the software, but I will not go into a subscriptiuon based option.

[Cintanotes](http://cintanotes.com/) was a possibility, with the following implications:

- Free
- Up to 3 Sections

However it does not:

- Export to HTML
- Password Protection
- Embedded Links

My current preference is [TagSpaces](https://www.tagspaces.org/) (which if someone flushed out and confirmed all the points for me, seems to be a valid option) - have note tested transporting the tags however.

Related Questions:

- [An open alternative for Evernote?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/35392/an-open-alternative-for-evernote)
- [Offline alternative to OneNote / Evernote](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/24747/offline-alternative-to-onenote-evernote)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [ToDoList](http://abstractspoon.weebly.com/)? Features it has:

- runs on Windows XP, 7, 8/8.1, 10,
- lets you encrypt your tasklist,
- no subscription as a desktop software,
- import from a range of formats (.mm, .csv, .gan, .ics, Microsoft Outlook, .nl, .txt, .tdl),
- export as .mm, .csv, .gan, .ics, Microsoft Outlook, .nl, .txt, .tdl, .html,
- it's probably not the most stunning UI, but it is ok,
- add links as Hyperlinks
- attach PDF/Docs etc,
- add categories to data,
- to-do lists,
- reminders,
- no dedicated code-box view with automatic syntax highlighting ([CherryTree](http://www.giuspen.com/cherrytree/) has it but it has no reminders from what I know).

Maybe worth a look :)