# Alternative to notion app

Tags: note-taking, evernote

How good is the notion as compared to Evernote? Is there any other good alternative for note-taking

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Offline alternative to OneNote / Evernote](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/24747/offline-alternative-to-onenote-evernote)

Answer (score 2):

https://bip.so/ is also a great alternative.

It has all the basic features that you need in a documentation tool. And has a bunch of other cool features including Youtube,twitter, figma, excalidraw, google sheets embeds.

It also a collaboration features with moderated git-workflow. And all of these features are present in the free version.

Comment: Welcome Surya.  What affiliation, if any, do you have with your recommendation?  Our community has a strict policy that all affiliations must be disclosed within answers.  Please edit your answer to disclose any affiliation, if appropriate.  Thanks, and again, welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://www.appflowy.io/ if you like Notion style. The tabular data structure of Notion is more powerful if you want to see data in various ways.

If it's just notes, then Evernote is a plain and simple and Joplin is a good alternate